# Java Decision Tree for Numeric Attributes & Classes

Tags: java, machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm looking for a java library for decision trees which accepts numeric attributes and classes/grades. Weka's J48 deals with discrete attributes but doesn't accept numeric ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not true, Weka's [J48](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/J48) (a variation of [C4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm#Improvements_from_ID3_algorithm)) does support numeric attributes. This is the main difference from the [ID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm) algorithm (among other things)

---

#### EDIT:

It appears you were referring to numeric output class rather than numeric input attributes.
In this case, you are looking for **model/regression trees**. Weka has an implementation of the M5 algorithm by *R. Quinlan* (the same guy who originally introduced the C4.5 algorithm for discrete classes) in **[weka.classifiers.trees.M5P](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/M5P)**. The algorithm is similar to the usual C4.5 except it uses standard deviation instead of entropy, also the leaf nodes contain a regression model (or simply the mean).

Comment: Right, but it doesn't support numeric classes, so you can't have a continuous spectrum of output from the model.